# to share videos stored on my sd card to smartv "do not appear"

Tags: release-loki, sharing

Do not appear the videos are stored to my SD card when I try to share by using sharing the Media library that comes by default in the system.

change the route but do not appear with the titles stored there.

what can I do?

[image: capture]

pd: I can access my SD card perfectly from my system. There is no complication, I can create folders and open documents, and videos.

thank you.

Comment: Does this work if you share the default videos directory instead of the SD card? I assume your TV supports DLNA?

Comment: exact! 
the default directory it works perfect, 
but if, instead of using the video folder of the system, I want you to read the video folder of the sd card. not appear any video. 

it is a pity that I have elementaryos installed on my chromebook 2, and I have very little hard disk storage. 
I have to save most of my data on the sd card or in the cloud.

Comment: Can it serve things from subfolders inside Videos? Just as a little experiment, maybe try creating a symlink? `ln -s /media/$USER/path/to/SD/card $HOME/Videos/sdcard`

Comment: Is that the symlink you created?

Comment: @MikeWild thank you for your patience. 
I don't have access.

Answer (score 1):

Back up all the files on your SD card, and format it to something else. (ext3, ext4, ntfs, fat32, etc.) It is possible that the tv does not support the file system on your SD card.

(IT IS A REQUIREMENT THAT YOU BACK UP **EVERYTHING** ON YOUR SD CARD BEFORE FORMATING IT!!!! ALL DATA ON THE CARD WILL BE LOST!!!!)

You may have to install a program such as gnome-disks to format removable devices. (It should be available in the AppCenter)